# twitter feed sentiment analysis

Tags: python-3.5, sentiment-analysis

I am doing Twitter feed sentiment analysis based on a keyword but I keep getting Error 406.

Mostly the error is coming in sentiment_Analysis function because I checked removing that and I get no error.

Please find my code below:

```html
from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import urllib.error

consumer_key='qr****************T1' #consumer key
consumer_secret='ZbkO**********************U9Y'  #consumer secret
access_token='989***************************2kd'   #access token
access_token_secret='Fv****************************qY7'  #access secret

#For sentiment Analysis we will be using Sentigem API key
akhil_auth= "297**********************************hB"

def sentiment_Analysis(text):
    encoded_text=urllib.parse.quote(text)
    #API_Call= "https://api.sentigem.com/external/get-sentiment?api-key="+akhil_auth+"&text="+text
   # output=urllib.urlopen(API_Call).read 
    output = urllib.request.urlopen(API_Call)
    return output

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self,data):
        tweet= data.split(',"text":"')[1].split('","source')[0]
        sentimentRating=sentiment_Analysis(tweet)

        saveTweets= tweet+'::'+sentimentRating+'\n'
        output=open('output.csv','a')
        output.write(saveTweets)
        output.close()
        print("Conversion successful.")
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print (status)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    stream = Stream(auth, l)
    #topic = input("Read tweets cotaining: ")
    stream.filter("Burger King")
```